Analysing 42v to 3.3v DC converter circuit & component identification
I'm analysing a circuit responsible for generating 3.3v for a stm32f103c8t6 on a battery management system(10s). Its a completely proprietary battery management system with nothing online about it so giving the modal number is useless  im analysing this circuit because potentially i can steal it for my benefit on my project BMS but im having trouble identifying the 2 large LDO looking components labelled as RIC BH the ON with a circle next to them suggests it is by ONSEMI. im interested in this specific circuit because its requirements are that it will be efficient and have little parasitic draw (i cannot test my multimeter is quite inaccurate).
I made a image with trace layout red trace is from B+ E.g. 42v & purple trace is what goes into the RIC BH devices then yellow trace is what goes into the HOLTEK 3.3v regulator.

here is empty image if you want to see trace layout yourself:

Could someone explain how this circuit would work? and is it really suitable for 24/7 battery powered BMS? thxz

Looks like a simple linear pre-regulator for the LDO. The two big transistors are connected in parallel, and the little transistor (G1k) is connected as a Darlington combination with them. There's a resistor and a (presumably Zener) diode on the little transistor's base.
So it's just brute-force dropping the voltage from 48 V to something more palatable to the LDO, dissipating the excess power in the two big transistors.

thanks for the explanation Dave. I wonder is this better than a switching power supply? for something that will always be connected to the battery is it efficient?

Based on the values of the resistors that I see, it seems that the current is miniscule, so yes, it probably is as efficient as a switcher would be.

Ok, great! I know what that small transistor is now, it is NPN. however what are those big ones? EDIT: I presume it is also a NPN transistor. but im not sure.
